# Why alcohol can't help with OCD?

Tags: neurophysiology, medicine, psychoneuropharmacology

I was thinking about influence of ethanol on our brain.
We know, that ethanol can affect GABA receptors and increase flow of chlorine in our brain cells. So it makes signal weaker and slow our CNS activity down.

People with OCD usually take minor/major tranquilizers (and many other ofc.) that have similar effect. 
I understand, that alcohol (ethanol) can't stay in our CNS as long as tranquilizers do and it also causes many bad influences, but if we put these bad effects away, could alchohol potentionaly help people with OCD for a short time?

I guess no, but i don't know much in neuropharmacology, so explain me please.

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting idea. How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: The close-vote on the question being self-help is off. It is a legitimate question, especially in the light of the tendency for psychiatric patients to self-medicate. +1

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-alcohol-cant-help-with-OCD Got some answer on quora, if smb is interested.